# Rigged model teleports everytime I render the image

Tags: rendering, animation, image, timeline

Been trying to solve this for 2 hours straight and nothing and my only hope is here. I'm still kinda new to all this but had thought I got an idea of this until this annoying thing happened.

[image: Down in the animation it doesn't matter if it's at frame 0 or 1, if you move it the model will go flying somewhere else]

[image: Now in the second one I moved both the key and the timeline and it does exactly what I don't want it to.]

Comment: What happened? Please elaborate. What do you need solved? What has gone wrong? What have you tried? what do these images indicate? This question is lacking key information.

Comment: You probably have keyframes registered, but haven't registered those keyframes for the frame you wanted to render.  Recommend: select all bones in pose mode, delete all keyframes in timeline.

Comment: Whenever I get one the models in place the other moves to another direction. No matter what I do with the key frames it just goes to another location.